# @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) does not work with @EmbeddedId

Tags: hibernate, identity

I am new to Hibernate and need some help here.

Previously I had only 1 primary key and I used the `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` to create a sequence in my database.

Now, I have changed to composite primary keys using `@EmbeddedId` and below my new `Employee.java`.

For some reason, the increment sequencing no longer works. It just stays at 0 for all my new entries.

Some clarification of this would be most appreciated. And how can I go about automatically incrementing the value?

Thank you!

**Employee.java - NEW**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private EmployeePK pk;
    private String name;
    private String username;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(String username, String name) {
        super();
        this.pk = new EmployeePK(username);
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Embeddable
    public class EmployeePK implements Serializable {

        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int employeeId;
        private String username;

        public EmployeePK() {
        }

        public EmployeePK(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

        public int getEmployeeId() {
            return employeeId;
        }

        public void setEmployeeId(int employeeId) {
            this.employeeId = employeeId;
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + getOuterType().hashCode();
            result = prime * result + employeeId;
            result = prime * result + ((username == null) ? 0 : username.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            EmployeePK other = (EmployeePK) obj;
            if (!getOuterType().equals(other.getOuterType()))
                return false;
            if (employeeId != other.employeeId)
                return false;
            if (username == null) {
                if (other.username != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!username.equals(other.username))
                return false;
            return true;
        }

        private Employee getOuterType() {
            return Employee.this;
        }

    }

    public int getEmployeeId() {
        return pk.getEmployeeId();
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return pk.getUsername();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are using Postgres, than In DB change Datatype from int to serial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`@GeneratedValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html) JavaDoc mentions:

> The GeneratedValue annotation may be applied to a primary key property or field of an entity or mapped superclass **in conjunction with the Id annotation**. The use of the GeneratedValue annotation is only required to be **supported for simple primary keys**. Use of the GeneratedValue annotation is **not supported for derived primary keys**.

---

However Hibernate probably supports such constructs according to their documenation ([2.2.3.2.4. Partial identifier generation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1150)). There is also an example code, so feel free to give it a try. This section of the documentation also contains following warning:

> **The Hibernate team has always felt such a construct as fundamentally wrong. Try hard to fix your data model before using this feature.**

So maybe better solution would be to rethink the model rather than to try to get this to work (if you can).