# Spring Data: How to set GenerationType strategy while working with @Embeddable and @Embedded

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to use `@Embeddable` and `@Embedded` in Spring data. Below is my approach.

**DeviceEntity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "device")
public class DeviceEntity implements Serializable {


      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      @EmbeddedId
      @AttributeOverrides({@AttributeOverride(name = "id" , column= @Column(name = "id",nullable = false))})
      private DeviceIdType deviceIdType;

.
```

**DeviceIdType:**

```
@Embeddable
public class DeviceIdType implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Column(name = "id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;
```

.
.
.

**Error Message:**

```
"code": "4715",
  "message": "Something went wrong",
  "additionalInfo": "null id generated for:class com.b.DeviceEntity; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class com.b.DeviceEntity"
```

Now, when I'm using GenertionType strategy, Im getting this exception.

Therefore, my question is: **How to set GenerationType strategy while working with @Embeddable and @Embedded ?**

Comment: Check if this helps -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33050629/generatedvaluestrategy-generationtype-identity-does-not-work-with-embedded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Embeddable` and `@EmbeddedId` are, most of the time, used for composite primary key, in JPA / Spring Data.

If you have a simple generated primary key, you'd better use the `@Id` annotation with the `@GenerationType`

Comment: @Id does not work for embedded objects (value types). It is meant only for entities.

Comment: That's right, but in his case, he's only embedding a long, which can be set in the main entity class

Comment: If you see it that way, then yes. The id could just be a part of the DeviceEntity instead of having an Embeddable object but it purely depends on his design, i.e. if he intends to have other fields which calls for a better OOP approach.